# RubyMine - How to change end of line character to Windows?

Tags: rubymine, linefeed

I changed a RubyMine settings few days back. It was related to changing the end of line character from '\r\n' to something else, so that it is only Mac compatible.

Now, each file I edit is changed completely in git diff. Also, I can't recall which setting
option was it.

Any guesses?

Comment: Not sure about RubyMine, but in other JetBrains' IDEs there is `File | Line Separator` (or the same in status bar, next to file encoding) which will allow to see and change line ending for **current file**. For **newly created** files check `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | General -> Line separator (for new files)`

Comment: You can post it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`File | Line Separator` (or the same in status bar, next to file encoding) which will allow to see and change line ending for **current file**.

For **newly created files** check `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Code Style | General -> Line separator (for new files)`